# How to clear the value entered in react-datepicker?

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using `react-datepicker` for our calendar control. Now the issue is that if the user entered an invalid date like 'djfdjfhjkhdf' then in this control nothing is there to validate. So I decided to write my own validation function and call that on blur event if the date is invalid then clear the text entered by the user. My code is like this:

```
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
focousOut(value) {
 this.handleChange('');
}
handleChange(date) {
 this.setState({ selectedValue: date });
 this.setState({ startDate: date });
}

<DatePicker
 selected={this.state.selectedValue}
 value={this.state.startDate}
 onChange={this.handleChange}
 onBlur={event => this.focousOut(event.target.value)} />
```

`validateDate` is a function that will return `true` or `false`, iff the date is valid then `true` else return `false`. How can I achieve this requirement, can you please assist me?

Comment: Instead of `selected`, change it to `value`.  Then set its value to empty string if you want to clear it.

Comment: @HemersonCarlin It is working but the new issue came if we clear the value and again try to enter the user defined input then value not showing in the text box.

Comment: focousOut(value) {
    this.handleChange('');
  }
  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({ selectedValue: date });
    this.setState({ startDate: date });
  }      <DatePicker
          selected={this.state.selectedValue}
          value={this.state.startDate}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={event => this.focousOut(event.target.value)}
        />

Comment: Try setting `null` instead of empty string. Also in onchange method combine the state like `this.setState({ selectedValue: date, startDate: date });`

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://codepen.io/amid/pen/OjqBzq

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution first add the control as:

```
<DatePicker
   selected={this.state.selectedValue}
   value={this.state.startDate}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
   onChangeRaw={(event) =>
   this.handleChangeRaw(event.target.value)}
   onBlur={event => this.focousOut(event.target.value)}
  />
```

Now, for the event add the following code:

```
handleChangeRaw(value) {
 this.setState({ startDate: value });
}
handleChange(date) {
 this.setState({ selectedValue: date });
}
focousOut(value) {
if (!validateDate(value)) {
    this.setState({ startDate: '' });
    this.setState({ selectedValue: moment() });
   }
}
```

`validateDate` is the function use for validating the date. If it returns `false` means invalid date, in this case resetting the value to initial state.